# Blender import camera from COLMAP has wrong direction

Tags: python, camera, coordinates, quaternion

I have the image.txt files from colmap, which includes the quaterion(QW, QX, Qy, QZ) and the translation(tx, ty, yz). I use the following code to do the transformation, but the direction of the camera is opposite. (should be direct inside, but direct outside)

```
import numpy as np
import bpy

#cam_data = np.loadtxt("cameras_pose.txt")


# sample data
cam_data = np.asarray([[-0.36476696823262345,0.023234429944508573,0.9238808623371452,0.11335507204667462,0.2643092436312764,-0.4627744163606162,4.525118487931772],
[-0.4054905199050235,0.035179478568114673,0.907024207991793,0.1079209371331166,0.3021461539009758,-0.44963208708908553,4.487193496243884],
[-0.44498629984439203,0.04694216063393536,0.8884523859473807,0.10215666600971764,0.3332381314236629,-0.43841177815187343,4.451058213992128],
[-0.4832757412383735,0.058705124977594836,0.868181639171128,0.09622321776992783,0.352540727853317,-0.4311898509770609,4.429843633647341],
[0.5201021779848836,-0.07003897699314113,-0.8464516703174265,-0.09004352266528506,0.3930999979872887,-0.4424100719537798,4.410415094718175],
[0.5554693178653287,-0.08129322321703367,-0.8233838408314181,-0.08297167846267772,0.40584591614055615,-0.44363835361054604,4.388432867705031],
[0.5897283310379344,-0.09242303827379236,-0.7987411860896823,-0.07543868511248913,0.40995873430639507,-0.4419034964054014,4.399626434833313],
[0.6230463233241476,-0.10311904020592387,-0.7723899864702667,-0.06777500527283144,0.4520027034475605,-0.44307975764642865,4.384405638423042],
[0.6549552499532656,-0.11369192223505492,-0.744668211978308,-0.0598082055088044,0.4785516086468784,-0.43684379155905334,4.330680113823206],
[0.685747771018359,-0.12458970645605517,-0.7152620247201971,-0.051260468020791476,0.49486879398471434,-0.44356999715487405,4.278724334858849],
[0.992426281686812,-0.0003958889474642249,-0.10747556558482971,-0.05948883501507541,-0.048720473486560875,-0.026204646129485094,2.8004058427698255],
[0.7153304814243133,-0.1351693897161802,-0.6842630762520066,-0.04260963397116011,0.5124225975959944,-0.4398810005707978,4.222826851917687],
[0.743259864382181,-0.14553128750886044,-0.6521195911231592,-0.03354783492207826,0.5086493021211627,-0.426523916034227,4.169771178687921],
[0.7699112067584281,-0.1559348439141461,-0.6183209857950522,-0.024499320127029604,0.48254201014524306,-0.38492033113053054,4.1412334139346845],
[0.7949627817243883,-0.16648883893805885,-0.5831611416967674,-0.015450728041178766,0.49539618281299447,-0.3711412052525336,4.111542476387624],
[0.8186352513004845,-0.17665337151331445,-0.5464313725570424,-0.006531978765913227,0.52340395014592,-0.3682745741918809,4.062152228676568],
[0.8405854496069631,-0.1870466858975028,-0.508354472267147,0.0023172677469452648,0.5614865636491215,-0.3672916155074743,3.978781497464174],
[0.786562421832458,-0.007673591751646279,-0.5595572448678875,-0.26106773501631064,0.5672791463272767,-0.1956690255167638,3.2073450381811566]])

def quaternion_rotation_matrix(Q):
    """
    Covert a quaternion into a full three-dimensional rotation matrix.
 
    Input
    :param Q: A 4 element array representing the quaternion (q0,q1,q2,q3) 
 
    Output
    :return: A 3x3 element matrix representing the full 3D rotation matrix. 
             This rotation matrix converts a point in the local reference 
             frame to a point in the global reference frame.
    """
    # Extract the values from Q
    q0 = Q[0]
    q1 = Q[1]
    q2 = Q[2]
    q3 = Q[3]
     
    # First row of the rotation matrix
    r00 = 2 * (q0 * q0 + q1 * q1) - 1
    r01 = 2 * (q1 * q2 - q0 * q3)
    r02 = 2 * (q1 * q3 + q0 * q2)
     
    # Second row of the rotation matrix
    r10 = 2 * (q1 * q2 + q0 * q3)
    r11 = 2 * (q0 * q0 + q2 * q2) - 1
    r12 = 2 * (q2 * q3 - q0 * q1)
     
    # Third row of the rotation matrix
    r20 = 2 * (q1 * q3 - q0 * q2)
    r21 = 2 * (q2 * q3 + q0 * q1)
    r22 = 2 * (q0 * q0 + q3 * q3) - 1
     
    # 3x3 rotation matrix
    rot_matrix = np.array([[r00, r01, r02],
                           [r10, r11, r12],
                           [r20, r21, r22]])
                            
    return rot_matrix

def rotationMatrixToQuaternion3(m):
    #q0 = qw
    t = np.matrix.trace(m)
    q = np.asarray([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype=np.float64)

    if(t > 0):
        t = np.sqrt(t + 1)
        q[3] = 0.5 * t
        t = 0.5/t
        q[0] = (m[2,1] - m[1,2]) * t
        q[1] = (m[0,2] - m[2,0]) * t
        q[2] = (m[1,0] - m[0,1]) * t

    else:
        i = 0
        if (m[1,1] > m[0,0]):
            i = 1
        if (m[2,2] > m[i,i]):
            i = 2
        j = (i+1)%3
        k = (j+1)%3

        t = np.sqrt(m[i,i] - m[j,j] - m[k,k] + 1)
        q[i] = 0.5 * t
        t = 0.5 / t
        q[3] = (m[k,j] - m[j,k]) * t
        q[j] = (m[j,i] + m[i,j]) * t
        q[k] = (m[k,i] + m[i,k]) * t

    return q

cam_quaternion = np.asarray([d[:4] for d in cam_data])
cam_position = np.asarray([d[4:] for d in cam_data])



bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)

scn = bpy.context.scene
for i in range(len(cam_position)):
    cam = bpy.data.cameras.new(name=f"cam_{i}")
    cam_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(f"cam_{i}", cam)
    cam_obj.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
    
    # calculate the position (camera centers)
    cam_obj.location = -np.dot(quaternion_rotation_matrix(cam_quaternion[i]).T, cam_position[i])
    # calculate the rotation
    quaternion_ = rotationMatrixToQuaternion3(quaternion_rotation_matrix(cam_quaternion[i]).T)
    cam_obj.rotation_quaternion[0] = quaternion_[0]
    cam_obj.rotation_quaternion[1] = quaternion_[1]
    cam_obj.rotation_quaternion[2] = quaternion_[2]
    cam_obj.rotation_quaternion[3] = quaternion_[3]
    scn.collection.objects.link(cam_obj)
    
bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(filepath="scene_with_cameras.glb", export_cameras=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this `cam_obj.rotation_quaternion = (quaternion_[1], quaternion_[2], -quaternion_[3], -quaternion_[0])` give you intended result?

Comment: sorry, it does not.